# How to integrate voice commands / actions into my application

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I want to add a simple feature to my application, where user would say

"Open ???? application"

and I open it for him, just like Google app and Google Assistants app do.

But here's a few notices about my requirements, so please don't answer unless you are sure that answer fulfill this requirements.

**1- I don't want to restrict user to English as Google Assistant does**

"Open ??? application" could be in any language (Spanish, Indian, Arabic, etc.), not just in English.

**2- I want to give the user the ability to "Assign" a custom word(s) to do specific action.**

So if the user don't want to say "Open Facebook app" everytime wants to open Facebook, the user could assign its own command.

Example: User assigned with his own voice (Or written via EditText) the word "FoFo" to open Facebook. And "ToTo" to open Twitter.

**Are my 2 requirements could be accomplished?**

If the answer is yes, what APIs and Libs provided to accomplish this?

Whoever help me to accomplish my task will receive at least 50 point reward.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I believe you're just using Android, you can use features like the built-in [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) class to handle speech input. What you as the developer get back will be the user's raw transcription.

From here, you can use string matching or [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to match that transcription against certain patterns that you have defined, such as `open .*? application` to match "facebook" or "twitter" or other apps.

If you want to add user-supported shortcuts, you can build [a database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) or some other persistent data structure of patterns or strings to match. In your recognition algorithm you can iterate through the array to find matching patterns.

Note that the Google Assistant is not limited to English, but has built out language support for a number of different languages.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I will check it out to see if it fits my needs.